# Access Angular-Material SCSS Variables (Angular4)

Tags: sass, angular-material, angular-material2

How to access certain **SCSS** variables in Angular-Material (Angular4)?

For example, the default toolbar has a CSS class as follow:

```
.mat-toolbar {
    display: flex;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 16px;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

I want to get the padding value, i.e. `16px`, store it as `$fatty-padding` and then use it in my custom class, for example:

```
.custom-toolbar {
    padding: $fatty-padding $fatty-padding;
    margin: 0 $fatty-padding;
}
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular Material styles are written without variables:

[image]

So there is no easy way to get this styles and store to the variable in SCSS.

Comment: What about colors? Isn't it possible to get the default theme colors? It feels like something that would be useful.

Comment: @user276648, I have tried, but failed, I can't extract the specific color from Angular Material's theme. So there are two cases: 1. I don't have enough skills. 2. It's not possible. I can't really say, what case is it, but when I'm looking at AM theme, I feel that it should be possible.